# Functions in ~/.bash_profile not found in an interactive shell

Tags: bash, profile

I thought that whatever lies in .bash_profile(or .profile) which is sourced in a login-shell, is available in an interactive shell.

My goal is to have available a list of functions, either in a login shell or in an interactive shell.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1, and i don't use .profile, but instead .bash_profile.(.profile has been renamed)

So currently what i have done, i have inserted the functions in .bash_profile, but when opening an interactive terminal they are not available, only if i use `bash -l`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions defined in `.bash_profile` are only available in the shell that reads `.bash_profile` and not available in sub shells.

When you open a terminal window you may be opening a *non* login shell.  Some terminal programs may let you open a login shell (eg `gnome-terminal` has it at `edit` -> `profile preferences`).

However if you shell out of another program (eg run `:sh` from `vi`) then you won't see these functions.

Normally, however, functions and things you want set on every shell should be placed in `.bashrc`.